# Why does BigQuery scan entire table although it's partitioned by hour?

Tags: google-bigquery

This table is partitioned by hour:

```
SELECT *
FROM `blockchain-etl-internal.crypto_ethereum_partitioned.logs_by_topic_0xd78`
WHERE block_timestamp >= '2020-11-14 00:00:00' and block_timestamp < '2020-11-14 01:00:00'
ORDER BY block_timestamp DESC
```

But whatever filter on the block_timestamp I specify BigQuery scans the entire table. You can see that table size and the amount of data scanned in a query to make sure.

Isn't BigQuery supposed to only scan data in partitions that are filtered out?

Comment: what is the size of the table?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant around 400MB

Comment: your filter is not by hours but rather by date, have you tried filtering by hour and see if it still scans whole table?

Comment: Just updated the question with filter by hour. It still scans the entire table. btw the table in the question is public

Comment: if you check partitions info of that table (via $__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__ for example) you will find that there is no partitions and all data belong to so called __UNPARTITIONED_ partition - that would explain your question - but now the real question is how it is possible as table clearly set to be partitioned by hour ??!!

Answer (score 1):

This is because all rows in the table is still in the `UNPARTITIONED` partition and has not been repartitioned into their corresponding partitions. Repartitioning is triggered only when there's enough data (byte size is at least a certain threshold) (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaming_into_partitioned_tables).

At the moment, this threshold is set at 5gb, while the table has around 400mb as you stated.

Comment: are those 5gb somewhere documented? somehow I don't remember this number :o(